# Why does xdotool seem to fail in Ubuntu with gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, automation, xdotool

I'm using gnome 3 with Ubuntu 17.10. I'm trying to open my text-editor of choice and gnome-terminal on startup and have them snap to the right resp. left corner of the screen, as seen in the picture below.

[image: Desired split screen in gnome 3]

With my old 16.04 using unity I achieved this with `xdotool` in a startup script and it worked fine. Obviously the shortcuts have changed from <kbd>Super</kbd>+(<kbd>Num_4</kbd> resp. <kbd>Num_6</kbd>) in Unity to <kbd>Super</kbd>+(<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>) in Gnome3, as I found out the hard way:

[image: Gnome3 shortcuts for split on right/split on left]

So I changed the `xdotool` commands in my startup script accordingly for 17.10:

```
subl && 
    xdotool key --delay 500 --window "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" Super+Left # Ctrl+Alt+83 on old Ubuntu

gnome-terminal && 
    xdotool key --delay 500 --window "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" Super+Right # Ctrl+Alt+85 on old Ubuntu
```

And expected it to work. I checked that it does run on startup. The terminal and sublime open fine, but no window snapping is performed. If I press the shortcut keys myself, the window snap in place. What am I doing wrong?

I'm open to alternative ways, as long it achieves my goal.

**Edit:** In the comments I was asked if I was using [wayland (yutani) or Xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used)

```
┌─27-12:46[jan@jcgbx:~] $ 
└▪ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Comment: Are you logging into a wayland session? If so xdotool won't work well

Comment: Not sure. If I were, what would be another method for my desired outcome?

Comment: x11 it is then.

Comment: Reduce the "delay" in your xdotool options, but instead await execution of the command using a sleep command before, e.g. `sleep 0.5 && xdotool ...`. Long delays in xdotool cause keyboard repeat to kick into action and probably does not work as expected.